# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. even with connection open

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to update a sql db in an "IF THEN" statement but I am getting :

ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

When I run my code.

```
Private m_cn As New SqlConnection
If oldcost <> newcost Then
            'Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            m_cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=tires;Integrated Security=True"
            m_cn.Open()
            Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            'm_cn.Open()
            mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tire_price_changes (change_date, old_cost, old_retail,new_cost,new_retail,tire_id) VALUES (@change_date, @Nold_cost, @old_retail, @new_cost, @new_retail, @tire_id)"

            Try
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@change_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = tiredate
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@old_cost", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = oldcost
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@old_retail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = oldretail
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@new_cost", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newcost
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@new_retail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newretail
                mycommand.Parameters.Add("@tire_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = m_introwposition
                mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Success")
            Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
```

Comment: You need to attach the connection to the command object, something like `mycommand.Connection = m_cn`.

Comment: Ed, that worked... thanks! I am not sure why I got a -1 for my post though.... :(

Comment: I don't get it either: you have a targeted question and a code sample, and you included the error message. I just gave you an up-vote, and it looks like you're in positive territory with this question now :)

Answer (score 1):

It won't be initialized this way. Either manually set `myCommand.Connection` property or create the command using CreateCommand:

```
myCommand = m_cn.CreateCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not connecting the command and the connection.

Try this before executing it:

```
mycommand.Connection = m_cn;
```

You can also ask the connection object to create the command object for you, in which case it will set this itself:

```
Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = Connection.CreateCommand()
```

Additionally, remember to call `Dispose` on these objects when you're done with them.

Comment: I will call dispose now that it is working. Just out of curiosity, what happens if I do NOT dispose? Does the app become a memory hog over time? I do not have enough experience to have learned the hard way (YET!).... thanks again so much for your help!

Comment: It will consume connections until the garbage collector gets to it, which depending on how often/much you run this code might not be fast enough. By default you can have 100 live SQL Server connections in a .NET app.

Comment: But that is actually besides the point. You should take heed to look at the documentation (or available methods) on new objects you use and any objects that implement `IDisposable`, it is *your* responsibility to call `Dispose` on it when you're done. In C# you can use the `using (xxx) { ... }` construct, but I'm unsure if VB.NET has something similar

Comment: thanks! It is nice to learn the correct way to code without always learning  the hard way.